# thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: exception, hadoop, mapreduce

Trying to run a job, but i keep getting this error. I do not know how to resolve it. Is there something im missing? What is wrong here?

This is in my shell

```
[cloudera@localhost home]$ hadoop jar cloudera/MinMaxCountDriver.jar MinMaxCount /user/cloudera/Comments.xml /user/cloudera/SuperUserXML/
```

This is the error i am getting 
    ***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MinMaxCount***
    ....
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:201)

Here is my driver.

```
public class MinMaxCountDriver {
public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String [] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

    if(otherArgs.length !=2 )
    {
        System.err.println("You need 2 Arguement");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    ...

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0: 1);

}

}
```

Comment: Is your class in a package?

Comment: I have a driver class, a mapper and a reducer all packaged into MinMaxCountDriver.jar

Comment: Yes but are your classes in a package?  Like com.example.plugin...

Comment: Yes. The Driver, Mapper and Reducer are all in the same package, along with a writable class. all 4 are packaged into the .jar

Comment: Again... not what I'm asking.  The beginning of your `.java` should have a package specifier like `package com.example.....`, you need to qualify your class name with that package.. like `com.whatever.MinMaxClass`

Comment: Yes, Mine does. Each class in the .jar has [package MapRedDesign;] at the top. Is this what you mean?

Comment: have you included this line in your driver  job.setJarByClass(MapperAndReducerCode.class);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each class in the .jar has [package MapRedDesign;] at the top.

Based on your comments, make sure you fully qualify your class name with the package, otherwise Java will have no idea where to find it.

```
hadoop jar cloudera/MinMaxCountDriver.jar MapRedDesign.MinMaxCount /user/cloudera/Comments.xml /user/cloudera/SuperUserXML/
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic command to run MR jobs is

```
hadoop jar myjar.jar classname inputfolder outputfolder
```

For me  it works without classname also

```
myproject
  |
  |
   -----> mypackage
           |
           |
           ---->Driver.java
           |
           |
           ---->Mapper.java
           |
           |
           ---->Reducer.java
```

If this is the tree I need not want to specify the classname

```
hadoop jar driver.jar in out
```

But

```
myproject
      |
      |
       -----> mypackage
      |        |
      |        |
      |        ---->Driver.java
      |        |
      |        |
      |        ---->Mapper.java
      |        |
      |        |
      |        ---->Reducer.java
      | 
      ----> mypackage2
               |
               |
                ---->Driver2.java
               |
               |
               ---->Mapper2.java
               |
               |
               ---->Reducer2.java
```

For this I need to specify my classname which driver class I am trying to execute.

```
hadoop jar driver2.jar mypackage2.Driver2 in out
```